# C++ Dialog Box TAB key not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++, dialog

I have tried everything but couldn't get the TAB key working to move the focus from one control to another control in a resource dialog. Here is the code:

```
IDD_DLG_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 219, 198
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "Caption"
FONT 8, "Tw Cen MT", 400, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
        DEFPUSHBUTTON   "Done",IDOK,162,175,50,16
        EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1,27,13,185,12,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD
        PUSHBUTTON      "Add",IDC_Add,109,30,33,13,WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD
        LISTBOX         IDC_LIST1,7,49,205,121,LBS_SORT | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD
        EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT2,27,31,81,12,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD
        LTEXT           "Name",IDC_STATIC,7,33,18,11
        LTEXT           "Link",IDC_STATIC,7,15,15,11    
        PUSHBUTTON      "Delete",IDC_DEL,144,30,33,13 | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD
        CONTROL         "Autorun at startup",IDC_CHECK1,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,7,174,70,10 
        PUSHBUTTON      "Edit",IDC_EDIT,179,30,33,13,WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD
END
```

Main While loop:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,int nCmdShow)
        {
            MSG msg;
            HACCEL hAccelTable;

            // Perform application initialization:
            if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow)) return FALSE;
            hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDC_STEALTHDIALOG);
            while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
            {
            if((!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))||(!IsDialogMessage(msg.hwnd,&msg))) 
                        {
                            TranslateMessage(&msg);
                            DispatchMessage(&msg);
                        }
            }
    }
```

Please identify the problem here. Thanks.

Comment: According to this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/71450 hwnd parameter of IsDialogMessage should be dialog hwnd, and not msg.hwnd.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `||` to a `&&`. At the moment, if `TranslateAccelerator` returns `0` (which it will unless an accelerator key has been pressed), `IsDialogMessage` will never be called - and that's what handles the tab key.

(Additionally, as Marco A. implies in his answer, you should pass the `HWND` of your dialog, and not `msg.hwnd` as the first parameter of the `IsDialogMessage` call. But this is immaterial unless `IsDialogMessage` actually gets called, which it almost always won't while you have `||` instead of `&&`).

Comment: The second issue is explained in this blog entry: [Using the TAB key to navigate in non-dialogs, redux](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131009-00/?p=2983).

Answer (score 0):

According [to this post](http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/microsoft/t-how-to-use-translateaccelerator-with-isdialogmessage-2628740.html) and confirmed by [this kb](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/71450) article:

> TranslateAccelerator() sends WM_COMMAND messages to the window whose 
>   handle you pass as an argument to TranslateAccelerator().
>
> You are probably calling TranslateAccelerator() passing the hwnd member 
>   of your MSG structure; this will be the handle of the window that has 
>   the focus. You should pass the handle of your main windows instead.

And that applies to your code.